# Using jQuery to find matching text in any child text node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, textnode

I'm a bit rusty on my jQuery (been a few years!) I have to assume this has been asked 100 times but I'm not searching for the right terms it seems.

I'm trying to grab all of the descendant text nodes of an object, and then, if there's a match to a text string, do something with that object. Here's why I have now:

```
$(".my-item").each(function(){
    var content = $(this).find('*').text();
    if (content.indexOf('mySearchString'>0)){
        //do something
    }
})
```

I can't seem to get this to find *all* text, however. Just the direct descendents. Sample HTML:

```
<div class="my-item">
    this text is part of the var 'content'
    <div>
        this text is not
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access the `textContent` of each node, and you could do directly in the filter, and return the matches, or use a regular `each` loop if you want to work with them directly

```
$(".my-item").each(function(){
    var $children = $(this).children();

    $children.contents().each(function(i,node){
        if (node.nodeType === 3 && node.textContent.indexOf('mySearchString') !== -1) {
            //do something
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/afqz9ans/)

Comment: Won't this only search to a depth of the children of `.my-item`?  Wouldn't something recursive be a better solution here?

Comment: Is there a way to do this 'en masse'? In other words, I'm fine grabbing ALL the text nodes and smashing them all together as one large string. I don't need to actually parse each one separately.

Comment: @Pineda - that's what `children()` does, it gets the immediate children?

Comment: @DA. sure you can, but then why use `contents`, all you'd need is `text()` if you don't need specific textNodes

Comment: @adeneo: I was expecting this to only work for 1st gen children of `.my-item`.  I didn't think it would work for 2nd 3rd, etc children/grand-children...

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry. I need to edit my question. I am searching for *all* descendents. So `children()` is the wrong selector. I do think `text()` is what I can use, though!

Comment: @Pineda - it only works for "grand children" of `.my-item`, as `children` gets the immediate children of `.my-item`, and then `contents` does the same, it gets the immediate children of the children. If the OP wants something else, a description of what that is would be great.

Comment: @DA. - https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/wdw9u22c/ you'd probably have to use `html()` as `text()` would remove tags. But this all depends on the use case

Comment: @adeneo thanks for the help! Alas, I think I'm a complete idiot. I was using some alerts to debug and didn't realize the alerts were truncating the string. 'doh!

Comment: @DA. - no problem. Next time use the console, it's a lot more reliable.

Comment: @adeneo yep. Man, I really am rusty. :)